# Looping dataframes based on their alphanumeric names,and creating a column in each of those dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have multiple dataframes named `df1,df2...df100`. I want to create a new column called file and have values filled with their file names in each of these files. Eg. `df1['file'] = 'df1'`
loop it for all the dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables**

It is poor practice to explicitly name a variable number of variables. You should use a dictionary instead. For example, given 100 dataframes with data read from files:

```
dfs = {f : pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_paths}
```

With this set-up you can easily also include filename in a new series via [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
dfs = {f : pd.read_csv(f).assign(file=f) for f in file_paths}
```